# Threading conversion between C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, migration

I would like to convert the following C# code to VB.NET

```
public byte[] TextToBytes(string textToSpeak)
{
    byte[] byteArr = null;

    var t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ss.SetOutputToWaveStream(memoryStream);
            ss.Speak(textToSpeak);
            byteArr = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    });
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
    return byteArr;
}
```

I have tried various things and used an online converter, but even the online converter was not sure how to handle the Thread thing.

Could somebody lend a helping hand?
Thank you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: BTW, that thread is completely useless.

Comment: @SLaks I got it from a posting here on SO. It was stated as a way to keep an ASP.NET website responsive.

Comment: @tmighty It starts and then blocks the caller until finished. You should probably understand threads before copying and pasting code. Otherwise you're in for a world of debugging pain.

Comment: @SLaks can you please explain to me why this thread is useless please , asking this question as a learner and curious about it

Comment: @PierreOverFlow: How might you expect it to be at all useful?

Comment: As it is, it's worth than useless. It's armful performance wise.

Comment: @SLaks I always read your answers and I also trust your answers, I asked you that coz you know something that I can't figure out myself. So I appreciate you if you explain why you think this thread is useless. Thats all, I just wanna learn something new.

Comment: @PierreOverFlow: You also need to learn how to think for yourself.  How might you expect this thread to useful? The main thread isn't doing anything else while it runs, because it immediately waits for it to finish.

Answer (score 1):

The `() =>` in C# denotes a lambda expression.  The same is denoted in VB by `Function()` or `Sub()`, depending on whether a value is returned or not.

```
Dim t = New System.Threading.Thread(Sub()
    Dim ss As New SpeechSynthesizer()

    Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
        ss.SetOutputToWaveStream(memoryStream)
        ss.Speak(textToSpeak)
        byteArr = memoryStream.ToArray()
    End Using
End Sub)
```